# "Unexpected identifier" when adding extends/block to wintersmith-jade content file

Tags: node.js, pug, stylus, wintersmith

I am making a static website using Wintersmith alongside the [wintersmith-stylus](https://github.com/jnwng/wintersmith-stylus) and [wintersmith-jade](https://github.com/smebberson/wintersmith-jade) plugins.

I want to add a specific CSS file in a help page. The help page is based off the "layout" template. When I try to use a block to insert the stylesheet into the html head, I receive the following error:

```
Line ##: Unexpected identifier
```

**layout.jade**

```
doctype html
html
    head
        block head
        link(rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/layout.css")
    body

...
```

**help.jade**

```
---
template: layout.jade
---

//- Error inducing code
extends ./layout.jade

block head
    link(rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles/help.css")
//- end of error inducing code

...
```

Even if I move the `extends` and `block head` lines on top of the metadata block containing `template: layout.jade`, I still receive the same error. Removing `extends ./layout.jade` results in the error lines position moving from 40 to 5 in my case.

My guess is the error is caused by the wintersmith-jade plugin, but even if that's the case I'm lost for how I would go about fixing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I wanted to use both Stylus and Jade (with Jade for both content and templates), I ended up moving over to [Harp](http://harpjs.com/). Harp not only has Stylus and Jade "built-in", but it's also slightly simpler than Wintersmith.

It's quite a workaround, but I'd say it's actually an upgrade at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using wintersmith-jade, but it looks like that plugin shouldn't affect the regular templates in `/templates` (which is what I think you're referring to).

Looking at `templates/article.jade`, it looks like you should use just `extends layout` instead of `extends ./layout.jade`.

The default templates also do not have the metadata block, but maybe that's necessary for the plugin you're using.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that `layout.jade` is indeed located in `/templates`, while `help.jade` is a piece of `content` made possible using wintersmith-jade.

Comment: Here are the locations of both files:
layout.jade: templates/layout.jade
help.jade: contents/help/index.jade

I tried your recommendation but unfortunately that didn't fix it -  not even the error line changed. 

I just noticed that if I delete the metadata block, the error remains exactly the same - that's fairly strange.